# Angular 2 headers and data

Tags: javascript, json, angular

In Angular 2, please can anyone show me a basic example of getting both the headers and data from a JSON api feed? I can see lots of examples on how to get the data only but no examples to get the headers. Please could you show me both the code in the component and then the code in the service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the headers should be in the response data. Most of the examples map the JSON immediately after receiving it and subscribing to the mapped stream. You can use RxJS `do` operator to intercept the stream and work with raw response.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(http:Http) {
    this.people = http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .do((data) => { 
        console.log(data.headers);
        // do your magic here
     })
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

If you want to manipulate the data differently on each emitted value of the stream, it would be best if you avoid mapping before you can read the data.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(http:Http) {

  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
}
```

Component:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  users: any[];
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(result => {
      let headers = result.headers;
      this.users = result.json();
      // rest of the magic
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are still using the old import blocks, should be `@angular/http` right?

Comment: Right. Dug up some old code to show the logic there. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I'm guessing you did this an as injectable so that it didn't have to use a service?

Comment: Well, it's actually a service and it should be made injectable, so it can be registered to DI container and passed to the component.

Comment: Ah ok thanks :) sorry to ask but would you be able to add to your answer and show me how the component would look? I'm getting confused as to which bit should do the 'map'ping and 'do'ing.

Comment: Oh ok, if you want to do different action depending each time, best course of action would be to map the response inside the observer function. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you so so much :) you've been incredibly helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Heres is the code for setting headers!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class AzureService {
headers: Headers;
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('ZUMO-API-VERSION', '2.0.0');

  }
getUsers(){
http.get(<URL>,this.headers)
    .do((data) => {
     })
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And for getting Headers from API, you can refer to @Adnan A. answer!