# Angular 2 Getting info from headers in request url

Tags: angular, http-headers

I have an angular 2  app that runs in an Iframe. Info that I need is being sent in the initial url (hitting my app) headers and query params.  How can i get info from the headers? This is not a get or post call from my app it is a external call to my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 headers and data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473434/angular-2-headers-and-data)

Comment: Maybe try using the Window.PostMessage method to allow cross document communication https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I did suggest that but they refused. Is what i am trying to do even possible?